# debugging newly created remote thread

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, malware

Im analyzing a particular malware sample and it seems to be doing the following in order to get write into the process memory of explorer.exe and execute code :-

1. OpenProcess(on explorer.exe)
2. NtAllocateVirtualMemory
3. NtWriteVirtualMemory
4. CloseHandle
5. CreateRemoteThread
6. WaitForSingleObject
7. GetExitCodeThread

Now what I wish to do is attach a debugger to the newly created thread in explorer.exe and debug it from its entry point onward. Would that be possible?

How could I go about doing the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can run another instance of debugger and attach it to exporer.exe, then look address of thread function in `CreateRemoteThread` parameters, and set breakpoint there.